On the free variables of the formula $\phi$ in the Axiom Schema of Replacement
From Wikipedia:

[O]ne instance of the schema is included for each formula $\phi$ in the language of set theory with free variables among $x, y, A, w_1,\ldots, w_n$; but $B$ not free in $φ$. In the formal language of set theory, the axiom schema is:
$$
\forall A \forall w_1, \dots, w_n \; \Big(\big[\forall x \in A \; \exists! y \; \phi(x, y, w_1, \dots, w_n, A)\big] \implies \exists B \; \forall y \; \big[y \in B \iff \exists x \in A \; \phi(x, y, w_1, \dots, w_n, A)\big]\Big)
$$
[...] For clarity, in the case of no variables $w_i$, this simplifies to:
$$
\forall A \; \Big(\big[\forall x \in A \; \exists! y \; \phi(x, y, A)\big] \implies \exists B \; \forall y \; \big[y \in B \iff \exists x \in A \; \phi(x, y, A)\big]\Big)
$$

I'm struggling to understand the usefulness of allowing $\phi$ to have other free variables besides $x$ and $y$. Even in the simplified version, I do not see the merit of including $A$ as a free variable in $\phi$.

All the applications of the axiom that come to mind are like so:
Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, and $\phi(x,y)$ represent the equation $y = 2x$. It holds that
$$\forall x \exists ! y (y = 2x)$$
and thus the axiom gives that there is some $B$ for which
$$\forall y\big[y \in B \iff \exists x \in A (y = 2x)\big]\Big).$$
or, more formally,
$$\forall y\big[y \in B \iff \exists x (x \in A \land y = 2x)\big]\Big)$$
e.g. $A = \{1, 3, 5\}$, then $B = \{2, 6, 10\}$.

Why do we allow $\phi$ to have free variables $w_1,\ldots,w_n,A$?

See Parameters in the ZFC axioms

For A and B, see the image into Wiki's entry we want that for a "functional formula" spanning set A the bunch of output values belong to a set B.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I may be starting to understand the need for the variables $w_i$: I'm guessing an example would be the formula $\phi(x, r, y)$ given by $x + r = y$ for $r\in\mathbb{R}$. However, I continue to be lost as to how $A$ could be a free variable of $\phi$ in a useful manner.
